# Sum of students' total scores for each subject

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

How do I get the overall sum of the total scores of students in individual subjects?

[image: scores table]

SCORES TABLE

| student_id | class_id | section_id | subject_id | test1 | test2 | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 7 | 5 | 6 | 11 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 17 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | 7 | 4 | 9 | 13 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 | 7 | 6 | 3 | 9 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 | 8 | 7 | 7 | 14 |

From the table above, I want the sum of all the total scores of students in individual subjects.
i.e the total score of students with ids 1, 2, 3, and 4 in subject_id 7 is 11, 17, 13, and 9 respectively.
Now what I want is to get the sum of all the total scores. which in this case would be 50.

This is what I tried.

```
 public function GetsumScore($subject_id, $session_id, $section_id, $class_id) 
    {
        $this->db->select_sum('total');
        $this->db->where('subject_id', $subject_id);
        $this->db->where('session_id', $session_id);
        $this->db->where('section_id', $section_id);
        $this->db->where('class_id', $class_id);
        return $this->db->get('scores')->row(); 
    }
```

Finally, how do I display the sum in a table in the view?

Comment: Please provide some information about the framework/library you are using. Since the answer to your question depends on how the framework/library works

Comment: do you mean the CodeIgniter framework?

Comment: please read: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=select_sum, keep in mind, you can include a second parameter to rename the resulting field and then read on [Generating Query Results](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the data directly yo the view this way

```
$data = array(
    'total_score' => $total_score // result came from GetsumScore method
);

$this->load->view('results_view', $data);
```

results_view.php

```
<html>
<?php 
//Access them like
echo "total score: " . $total_score; ?>
</html>
```